# join using two column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
    ProjectMaster
     ProjectID ITManagerID DevelopmentManagerID

--------------------------------------------------
        1         1000         1001

     UserTable

     UserID UserName
     ----------------
      1000   Sam
      1001   Ram

    Result 
      Project   ItManagerName DevManagerName
------------------------------------------------
        1          sam          ram
```

Help to write query

**Edit:**
I tried

```
select
    projectid,projectName,projectdescription,startdate,enddate,
    apsmanagerid,projectmanager,ragstatus,projectstatus,projectpriority,
    categoryid,inactivedate,comments,it.userName AS ITProjectManagerName,
    dev.userName as DevManagerName
from pmis_project p,pmis_user It,pmis_user dev
where p.DevprojectManager = It.userid
  and p.ITmanagerid = dev.userid
  and p.projectid IN (Select Projectid from SelectedProject)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `JOIN` a table as many times as needed.

In this case

- one `JOIN` to `Users` to get the ITManager's name.
- one `JOIN` to `Users` to get the DevManager's name.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  ProjectID
        , ITManagerName = m.UserID
        , DevManagerName = d.UserID
FROM    ProjectMaster pm
        INNER JOIN UserTable m ON m.UserID = pm.ITManagerID
        INNER JOIN UserTable d ON d.UserID = pm.DevelopmentManagerID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include the same table multiple times in the FROM clause of a SELECT query. If you're doing this, you frequently want to introduce an alias for one or more of these tables, so that they can be referred to in the rest of the query. You introduce an alias by adding `AS alias` after the name of the table, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table As t
WHERE
    t.Column = 'x' --<-- using the alias here
```

(the AS is actually optional)

Joining tables in a FROM clause is performed by using the `JOIN` keyword, and placing the conditions for the join in the `ON`:

```
FROM
    Table1 t1
        inner join
    Table2 t2
        on
             t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnB
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM ProjectMaster PM
>   INNER JOIN UserTable UT ON UT.UserId = ITManagerId
>   INNER JOIN UserTable UT1 ON UT1.UserId = DevelopmentManagerId